# Suspicious "find /" command uses ~90% of Disk IO

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

As I detect my server are very slow, I do some researches and detect in `iotop` a weird find command uses 80-96% disk io usage.

```
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                                                                                                  
 4992 idle nobody      7.82 M/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 89.69 % find / ...
```

the whole command is very large, `ps aux | grep find` gives me

```
root      4978  0.0  0.0  49340  2860 ?        SN   06:25   0:00 su nobody -s /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/find / -ignore_readdir_race      \( -fstype NFS -o -fstype nfs -o -fstype nfs4 -o -fstype afs -o -fstype binfmt_misc -o -fstype proc -o -fstype smbfs -o -fstype autofs -o -fstype iso9660 -o -fstype ncpfs -o -fstype coda -o -fstype devpts -o -fstype ftpfs -o -fstype devfs -o -fstype mfs -o -fstype shfs -o -fstype sysfs -o -fstype cifs -o -fstype lustre_lite -o -fstype tmpfs -o -fstype usbfs -o -fstype udf -o -fstype ocfs2 -o      -type d -regex '\(^/tmp$\)\|\(^/usr/tmp$\)\|\(^/var/tmp$\)\|\(^/afs$\)\|\(^/amd$\)\|\(^/alex$\)\|\(^/var/spool$\)\|\(^/sfs$\)\|\(^/media$\)\|\(^/var/lib/schroot/mount$\)' \) -prune -o -print0
nobody    4991  0.0  0.0   4500   684 ?        SNs  06:25   0:00 sh -c /usr/bin/find / -ignore_readdir_race      \( -fstype NFS -o -fstype nfs -o -fstype nfs4 -o -fstype afs -o -fstype binfmt_misc -o -fstype proc -o -fstype smbfs -o -fstype autofs -o -fstype iso9660 -o -fstype ncpfs -o -fstype coda -o -fstype devpts -o -fstype ftpfs -o -fstype devfs -o -fstype mfs -o -fstype shfs -o -fstype sysfs -o -fstype cifs -o -fstype lustre_lite -o -fstype tmpfs -o -fstype usbfs -o -fstype udf -o -fstype ocfs2 -o      -type d -regex '\(^/tmp$\)\|\(^/usr/tmp$\)\|\(^/var/tmp$\)\|\(^/afs$\)\|\(^/amd$\)\|\(^/alex$\)\|\(^/var/spool$\)\|\(^/sfs$\)\|\(^/media$\)\|\(^/var/lib/schroot/mount$\)' \) -prune -o -print0
nobody    4992  9.6  0.1  81004 63996 ?        DN   06:25  18:22 /usr/bin/find / -ignore_readdir_race ( -fstype NFS -o -fstype nfs -o -fstype nfs4 -o -fstype afs -o -fstype binfmt_misc -o -fstype proc -o -fstype smbfs -o -fstype autofs -o -fstype iso9660 -o -fstype ncpfs -o -fstype coda -o -fstype devpts -o -fstype ftpfs -o -fstype devfs -o -fstype mfs -o -fstype shfs -o -fstype sysfs -o -fstype cifs -o -fstype lustre_lite -o -fstype tmpfs -o -fstype usbfs -o -fstype udf -o -fstype ocfs2 -o -type d -regex \(^/tmp$\)\|\(^/usr/tmp$\)\|\(^/var/tmp$\)\|\(^/afs$\)\|\(^/amd$\)\|\(^/alex$\)\|\(^/var/spool$\)\|\(^/sfs$\)\|\(^/media$\)\|\(^/var/lib/schroot/mount$\) ) -prune -o -print0
```

for me it looks very suspicious even I kill the processes and take a look in `iotop` a second command starts

```
 4933 idle root       85.14 M/s  409.77 M/s  0.00 % 75.22 % sort -z
```

somebody knows whats this?

PS: The System is Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-210-generic x86_64)

Comment: Check `cron` of nobody user

Comment: `crontab -e -u nobody` is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches the [`updatedb.findutils(1)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/updatedb.findutils.1.html) command present in the package `locate`.

Its `/etc/cron.daily/locate` script invoked from system's daily *crontab* (usually at 06h25 as seen in `/etc/crontab`) has various [options to skip some paths and filesystems](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/findutils/-/blob/4.6.0+git+20160126-2/debian/locate.cron.daily?ref_type=tags#L19):

> ```bash
> # Global options for invocations of find(1)
> FINDOPTIONS='-ignore_readdir_race'
> # filesystems which are pruned from updatedb database
> PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre_lite tmpfs usbfs udf ocfs2"
> # paths which are pruned from updatedb database
> PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /usr/tmp /var/tmp /afs /amd /alex /var/spool /sfs /media /var/lib/schroot/mount"
> # netpaths which are added
> NETPATHS=""
> # run find as this user
> LOCALUSER="nobody"
> ```

which get converted to `find` options in the [`updatedb.findutils`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/locate/updatedb.sh?h=v4.6.0#n278) command.

All these match the content of OP's `ps aux` command, starting with `-ignore_readdir_race`.